# How to create a heatmap in python to scale three categories?

Tags: python, visualization, heatmap

I have a data set that has 24 data points, and each of them belongs to a category (3 categories in total). I want to create a heatmap that has three different colors to represent these 3 categories, and different shades of each color represents the number of each data point. The darker the shade will show the higher number. And I still want to keep the descending way of showing the datapoints from left to right. Is it possible to use seaborn to create such a heatmap? I have a screenshot of my data below:

Dataset

[image: 1]

I tried to use seaborn, but it seems something went wrong.

Comment: Please provide an example of the `seaborn` code you've tried so far and the incorrect output you get. I'm not sure how you're trying to use the example data you provided.

Comment: Sounds like you'd like to use a different colormap for each category. I don't think seaborn's heatmap function will let you do that. You may need to write a custom function to do this using lower level plotting functions (e.g. `matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection`): https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#